# How push HF model to the hub

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers, hub

I have a related issue can any one solve it?
[Problem described well here](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/typeerror-repository-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-token/33458/4)

I am expacting to pushing the model not only tokenizer and processor as :
[link](https://huggingface.co/AlhitawiMohammed22/test_pushing_to_hu/tree/main)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62525680/save-only-best-weights-with-huggingface-transformers/75997083#75997083

Answer (score 1):

you can follow this instruction [Link](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_sharing)

```
pt_model = DistilBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("path/to/awesome-name-you-picked", from_tf=True)
pt_model.save_pretrained("path/to/awesome-name-you-picked")
pt_model.push_to_hub("my-awesome-org/my-awesome-model")
```

you can call push_to_hub directly on your model to upload it to the Hub.
Specify your model name in push_to_hub:

```
pt_model.push_to_hub("my-awesome-model")
```

The push_to_hub function can also be used to add other files to a model repository. For example, add a tokenizer to a model repository:

```
tokenizer.push_to_hub("my-awesome-model")
```